# Reset system loop after installing any debian based distro

Tags: ubuntu, boot, system-installation, live-usb

I am trying to install Linux (Ubuntu).

The installation process is fine.

At the very end when it asks to restart computer, I restart my laptop and the message `Please remove installation medium, then press ENTER` shows up, so I remove my USB and press enter.

The computer restarts then a message saying `Reset System` shows up and the computer restarts again and the message shows up again, and so on for ever.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I have now tried with many Debian based distros and always get the same issue.

Comment: This could indicate you had Windows 10/11 installed and your firmware wants to restore your Windows installation or boot loader. I could be wrong. If that's the case, you may wipe your disk clean prior to installing Ubuntu.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yes i had windows on my computer a while ago, but since then i have had an arch based distro named garuda. To wipe my disk clear prior to installing ubuntu, do i do it fromn a live USB?

Comment: Yep, you could use https://www.system-rescue.org